# php replace html when using <<<EOD

Tags: php

I know I can concatenate php variable within html but I chose to use <<

```
<?
$template = <<<EOD
<table></table>
//bunch of stuff html here
<div id="placeholder"></div>
EOD;
?>
```

Now I want to replace the placeholder with my custom msg, how do I that in php? The $template got rendered before my $custom_msg come in.

Comment: Can you show us how you try to replace the placeholder by your custom message ? 
So we'll be able to understand what your trying to do and how to help you

Comment: you can try <div id="placeholder"><?php echo $custom_msg ?></div>

Comment: could you tell me what you want to do, give us an example.